# How to find string B missing characters based on string A and add them to string B?

Tags: swift, string

I have 2 strings.

```
var stringA = "LetDoItNow"
var stringB = "LetDo"
```

Is there a way that I can find characters that are not in string B based on string A and add them to string B in order that present in String A? If they are equal, no action needed.

stringA always contains all stringB characters in exact order of stringA.
 Another example is

```
var stringA = “GoodMorning”
var stringB = “GoodM”
```

stringB will always follow stringA order but it could be missing some stringA characters. String B will never be something like this

```
var stringB = “Morning”
```

The missing characters in the 1st case are "ItNow" and my expected result after checking is

```
stringB = "LetDoItNow"
```

I hope to get missing characters so that i can run this code
stringB += “missingCharacters”
Thank you so much!

Comment: Define "missing". Is it the part of A that is longer than B or letters that appear in A but not B?

Comment: What about `stringB = stringA` ?

Comment: I just edited my question

Comment: @KevinVuD your edit didn't clarify anything. "Equal" in what? In length or in content (`stringA == stringB`)?

Comment: There is no easy way to do this.  What happens if your string is "Leo"?  Does that "o" belong to the "Do" or the "Now". Also what happens when the string is "GetDoItNow"?

Comment: are your characters can be random or stringB could have part of stringA ? like substring ?

Comment: I just edited my question again. Sorry for any confusion

Comment: Do you have an example that doesn't result in stringB just being equal to stringA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `stringA.components(separatedBy`

```
 var stringA = "LetDoItNow"
    var stringB = "LetDo"


    if stringA.count > stringB.count {
        let component =  stringA.components(separatedBy: stringB)
        if component.count > 1{
            stringB = stringB+component[1]
        }
    }

        print(stringB)
```

You can Configure it better than this to make generic solution

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary - store all characters and occurrences in String B, then compare String A and add what you are missing.

```
func letdoitnow() {
    var dict = [Character:Int]()
    for each in stringB {
        dict[each] = (dict[each] ?? 0) + 1
    }

    for each in stringA {
        dict[each] = (dict[each] ?? 0) - 1
        if dict[each]! < 0 {
            b += String(each)
        }
    }
}
```

This does not care about order though - unsure if that matters to you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add *missing* characters that are in `stringA` but not in `stringB` to `StringB` then you can use the following function:

```
private func addMissingCharacters(stringA: String, stringB: String) -> String {
    if stringA == stringB {
        return stringA
    }

    var result = stringB
    for charachter in stringA {
        if !stringB.contains(charachter) {
            result.append(charachter)
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

Here is a usage example:

```
let stringA = "LetDoItNow"
let stringB = "LetDo"

let result = addMissingCharacters(stringA: stringA, stringB: stringB)
print("Result: \(result)") // Will print: LetDoINw
```

As you can see, the result is "LetDoINw" not "LetDoItNow", because 't' of "It" and 'o' of "Now" are there in `stringB` so they won't be added again.